In vue-konva what is the type of proxy that has getNode() function
I'm writing application in Vue 3's Composition API with TypeScript.
In my view I want to get new position of dragged v-group. To do that I need to get reference to the v-group and unwrap it from vue-konva proxy with getNode() function. As I am using TypeScript I need to know what is the type of element got from reference of v-group.
However, I'm unable to find documentation about the vue-konva proxy used for every konva object.
Here is my current code:
<template>
  <v-stage :config="configKonva">
    <v-layer>
      <v-group ref="mainGroupProxy" :config="mainGroupConfig" @dragend="groupDragEnd">
        <v-rect :config="getPixelConfig" />
      </v-group>
    </v-layer>
  </v-stage>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import Konva from "konva";
import { computed, ref } from "vue";

const configKonva = computed(() => ({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
}));
const mainGroupConfig = computed(() => {
  return {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    draggable: true,
  };
});
function getPixelConfig() {
  return {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 5,
    height: 5,
    fill: "black",
    stroke: "transparent",
  };
}

const mainGroupProxy = ref<Konva.Group | null>(null); // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
function groupDragEnd() {
  if (mainGroupProxy.value) {
    console.log("mainGroupProxy.value: ", mainGroupProxy.value); // returns proxy
    const mainGroup = mainGroupProxy.value.getNode(); // required to unwrap Konva node from Vue proxy
    console.log("X position: " + mainGroup.getX());
  }
}
</script>

This works and on drag end gives me the following results:

mainGroupProxy.value: Proxy(Object) {__v_skip: true, getStage: ƒ, getNode: ƒ}


X position: 91.00000546773309

However it is not correct, as the type of mainGroup should include the type of the vue-konva, e.g.:
const mainGroupProxy= ref<ProxyOfVueKonva<Konva.Group> | null>(null);

Where ProxyOfVueKonva is the actual type of proxy. Lack of this type causes typeScript errors.

I had to create needed type. Therefore edited last part is:
import { Transformer } from "konva/lib/shapes/Transformer";
type VueKonvaProxy<Group> = { getNode(): Group }; // THIS SOLVED THE PROBLEM
const mainGroupProxy = ref<VueKonvaProxy<Konva.Group> | null>(null);
function groupDragEnd() {
    if (mainGroupProxy.value) {
        console.log("mainGroupProxy.value: " + mainGroupProxy.value);
        const mainGroup = mainGroupProxy.value.getNode() as Transformer; // setting type Transformer is required for TypeScript to allow for use of required function
        console.log("X position: " + mainGroup.getX());
    }
}

